# When I run a selenium test for Firefox to create a user the test runs but I never see the user in my list

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

However, if I set up to run using Microsoft Edge the test completes and i can see the user just created in the list.  Here is my code.   Very confused.
As you can see all I change to run for Microsoft Edge is un-comment the setProperty line and then change the FirefoxDriver to EdgeDriver.  When I do that as I said the script runs and upon completion I log in and can see the user in the list while when using this code I cannot see the user.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    //    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Web Driver/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            baseUrl = "http://briotest.brio.viddler.com/";
            firstName = "Sam";
            lastName = "Bradford";
            email = "sbradford@mail.com";
            password = "Sooners1!";
            test();
      }

public static void test() throws InterruptedException {
        // get to login page and enter credentials
            driver.get(baseUrl + "/users/login");
            driver.findElement(By.name("email_address")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.name("email_address")).sendKeys("jfayefrank@yahoo.com");
            driver.findElement(By.name("password")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("*********");
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.button")).click();
        // Now on the assets view page.  Go to Users and select Create
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/header/div[2]/nav/div/ul[1]/li[6]/a")).click(); // Users tab
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create")).click();
        //  Enter new users credentials and submit 
            driver.findElement(By.id("email")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.name("password")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.name("first_name")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.name("first_name")).sendKeys(firstName);
            driver.findElement(By.name("last_name")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.name("last_name")).sendKeys(lastName);
            driver.findElement(By.id("email")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(email);
            driver.findElement(By.name("password")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(password);
            try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Could not perform pause");
            }
        //    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.button")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div/article/form/input[2]")).click();
            System.out.println ("User created!!!");
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to observe Firefox in motion when you run this to confirm it is executing (rather than just getting to the end without any Exception being thrown).

Comment: Yes I can see it running and it runs without issue.   The same code using the Microsoft Edge does add the user and I can see it in the User List View.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.   Thanks to a coworker my problem is resolved.  Apparently since Firefox was not maximized the Submit button was not really selected even though it appeared to do the action.   Once I added driver.manage().window().maximize(); my users were now visible in the list.   Did I mention the coworker was an intern...